# おじさま/おじさん = father of s.o. else?

Tags: meaning, words

i have a quick question - as far as I know, 叔父さん and 伯父さん both mean uncle - one younger, one older sibling - but sometimes I come across sentences where first it's written in romaji and it seems to be implied that a おじさま might really mean "your dad" - but then there's also the sligthly negative connotation of a おじさん that makes me wonder, if this is really true? Can おじさま mean "your father/your parent" in some cases? Thanks so much!

Comment: "it seems to be implied that a おじさま might really mean "your dad"" There is a lot of uncertainty here. Could you share the original sentence so we could know the context? Maybe it's not what you think it is.

Comment: I wonder if there has been a confusion with おやじさん. 

Comment: Are you getting confused by the fact that おじさん is also a way to address a man who is your senior, even if not directly related?

Comment: おじさん can refer to *any* middle aged guy. It includes someone else's dad, but you can even call a total stranger おじさん. おじさま is a respectful version of it (but it's rarely used in reality).